# Options for gulp-rigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

If i insert `.coffee` file in `.js`, then gulp-rigger "on the fly" compile it and concat. Is it possible to pass parameters? (`{ bare : true }`). It worked good, but only default setting =\ May-be somebody working with this plugin, or can look into the source code?

Comment: I have never used the plug-in but I quickly checked the source code. The only options allowed in the plug-in are `cwd`, `filepath`, `filetype` & `targetType`.

Comment: @ThomasBormans, yap, now i see in `Rigger.prototype._fork`. Anyway thanks, because on ru-stack I waited answer 3 days.

Comment: I have added it as answer if someone else in the future visits your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/kuzyk/gulp-rigger/blob/master/index.js), only these options are supported:

- cwd
- filepath
- filetype
- targetType